# Add shopify surcharge fee with variant product

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am creating a Shopify app so that user can add surcharge fee to the cart (custom fee). The custom fee will based on the total weight of the cart. To do that I create a product with many variants. For example, if the custom fee is 10eu then I add the product with variant 10eu to the cart.

I faced up with one issue. Shopify limits 100 variants for a product so my app will stop working after creating 100 variants. How can I clean up variants or how can I fix the issue?

Comment: So what you are saying is that you have more than 100 different surcharges? How about creating a product for $1 or so and then increment the number of the product to reach your desired amount, for example if your surcharge is $5 then add 5 items of the surcharge product ($1 x 5). This approach has its limitations but it's a bit more flexible than your current approach IMO. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, it seems weird to me that I have a product with quantity 289 for example to get 289$. I am thinking of when to clean up variants